# Multiple Input Boxes in AlertifyJS Prompt dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify, alertifyjs

The following code produces a prompt with a single input box, however i need to have two input boxes . Is this achievable ?

```js
alertify.prompt("Please enter Values","Default Text").set('onok', function(closeevent, value) { 
if (value == "" || value == " " )
{
    alertify.error("No value entered");
    return;
}
else
{
    updateItem(selectedItem,value);
}
}).set('title',"Update Values");
```

Answer (score 2):

So i was able to achieve this with the following code :

```html
<!-- the content to be viewed as dialog
  ***Define the two input boxes
  *** Note the input element class "ajs-input" that i have used here , this is the class used by AlertifyJS for its Input elements.
-->
<div style="display:none;" >
    <div id="dlgContent">
        <p> Enter Value One </p>
        <input class="ajs-input" id="inpOne" type="text" value="Input One Default Value"/> 

        <p> Enter Value Two </p>
        <input class="ajs-input" id="inpTwo" type="text" value="Input two default Value"/> 
       
    </div>
</div>

<!-- the script  -->

<script>
  var dlgContentHTML = $('#dlgContent').html();

$('#dlgContent').html(""); 
/* This is important : strip the HTML of dlgContent to ensure no conflict of IDs for input boxes arrises" */


/* Now instead of making a prompt Dialog , use a Confirm Dialog */


alertify.confirm(dlgContentHTML).set('onok', function(closeevent, value) { 
     var inpOneVal = $('#inpOne').val();
     var inpTwoVal = $('#inpTwo').val();
     /* Insert your code to work with the two values */     
    }).set('title',"Update");
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I am following your code to design a custom dialog box using alertify JS however, I cant seem to get my if statement to work. Please could you help out, I have pasted this as an question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210205/custom-dialog-box-javascript-alertifyjs