# Text area with upload attachments options HTML/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, textarea

I have created text area that allows user to type in their text as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Please type your favourite foods here and upload attachments if you want!</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to allow the user to allow be able to drag/drop or upload file attachments to the textarea but I am not quite sure how I can achieve this. I am quite new to web development and I am not sure what such feature would even be called. I have created a screenshot of what I would like, see below - something along the lines of gmail compose window. Please can someone help me, thanks.

[image]

Once the user has written and uploaded the files, I will be saving them to a database.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544977/how-to-use-jquerys-drop-event-to-upload-files-dragged-from-the-desktop

Comment: Hi @vahdet yes something along those lines but I want to use text area instead of a div because I also want the user to be able to type in text. Also, I would like to display the uploaded attachments on the window like shown in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the DropzoneJS library.

Create `Dropzone` object with the [options](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options) you need and use the [sending](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) event to add textarea text to the POST request.

Change the [default template](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html) and add your HTML inside div with `template-container` id. Then add [previewTemplate](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewTemplate) property to `myDropzone` options
with value

`document.querySelector('#template-container').innerHTML`

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: $('#my-dropzone').attr('action'),
    paramName: "file",
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 20,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    thumbnailHeight: 30,
    thumbnailWidth: 30,
    init: function() {
      this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
          formData.append('favouriteFoodText', document.getElementById('favourite-food-text').value);
        }),
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
    }
  }

  $('#my-dropzone').dropzone();
});
```

```css
#b-dropzone-wrapper {
border: 1px solid black;
}

#b-dropzone-wrapper .full-width {
  width: 100%
}

#b-dropzone-wrapper textarea {
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  width: 99%;
}

#my-dropzone {
  top: -5px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.0/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="b-dropzone-wrapper">
  <textarea rows=5 id="favourite-food-text" placeholder="please write some text here"></textarea>
  <form action="file-upload.php" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone full-widht" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit your entry" class="full-width" />
</div>
```

After submitting the form on the server side the transferred data will be parsed by PHP and saved in `$_POST` and `$_FILES` super global arrays.

Comment: Great, I will test this out now. Would this allow me to save the attachment to database as well as the text?

Comment: When I drag and drop file it doesn't seem to get attached/show up on the screen like shown in the image in post.

Comment: This code requires jQuery. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r3dtnukw/6/, could you take a look please. I cant seem to get it working.

Comment: even with jquery it doesnt seem to display/upload the data on the screen. Any idea why?

Comment: looking at the console, I am getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined

Comment: for some reason it says this 'var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");' is not defined.

Comment: Thanks now it displays the files on the screen, before I think the updated snippet werent showing. Would it be possible to overlay the drag-drop of files on top of the text area like in image shown/gmail compose example.

Comment: Thanks now it works, two questions 1., when it press the X button it doesnt remove the attachment and 2., can I upload this to database if I am don't use server side but only database e.g., Frebase.

Comment: Also, do i need to paste this code as well: document.querySelector('#template-container').innerHTML

Comment: DropzoneJS requires server-side file processing after submitting the form. Use `previewTemplate` for the template used for each dropped file.

Comment: I didn't write about previoustemplate. `previewTemplate` is a configuration option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174605/discussion-between-camelswriteincamelcase-and-jackie).